# Changing '?' to '&' in address bar

Tags: python, django

For example, in my web-app I have a link with url www.example.com/profile?name=name. When I click to that link, I'm getting a page, where I can change profile's information, **BUT** after clicking to that link, url in adress bar turns into www.example.com/profile&name=name.

More interesting: when I make some changes and click SAVE - url reverts to www.example.com/profile?name=name.

If I don't click SAVE, just refresh page, i'm getting error 404.

How can it be possible?

P.S My view function

```
@check_document_access_permission()
def notebook(request, is_embeddable=False):
  if not SHOW_NOTEBOOKS.get():
    return serve_403_error(request)

  notebook_id = request.GET.get('notebook', request.GET.get('editor'))

  is_yarn_mode = False
  try:
    from spark.conf import LIVY_SERVER_SESSION_KIND
    is_yarn_mode = LIVY_SERVER_SESSION_KIND.get()
  except:
    LOG.exception('Spark is not enabled')

  return render('notebook.mako', request, {
      'editor_id': notebook_id or None,
      'notebooks_json': '{}',
      'is_embeddable': request.GET.get('is_embeddable', False),
      'options_json': json.dumps({
          'languages': get_ordered_interpreters(request.user),
          'session_properties': SparkApi.get_properties(),
          'is_optimizer_enabled': has_optimizer(),
          'is_navigator_enabled': has_navigator(request.user),
          'editor_type': 'notebook'
      }),
      'is_yarn_mode': is_yarn_mode,
  })
```

Comment: Added code to post.

Comment: What do your relevant url entries look like?

Answer (score 0):

I found error.

In frontend was JS function, which incorrectly changed url.